# React Semantic UI - How to disable a child component based on parent

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

How does one disable the input box here, depending on whether a checkbox has been checked or not?

I have verified the checked property - it is in working order (shows true or false boolean values).
However, I can't seem to get the disabled property in Input to work.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Checkbox, Input, List } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CategoryCheckBox = ({ type = 'checkbox', name, mylabel, checked, onChange }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
      <List horizontal relaxed>
        <List.Item>     
            <Checkbox style={{ paddingLeft:"1em", paddingBottom: "1em" }} label={mylabel} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
            <List.Content>

                <Input style={{ maxWidth:"9em", paddingLeft:"1em" }} size='mini' focus placeholder='Min' disabled={checked === true ? true : false} />
                <Input style={{ maxWidth:"9em", paddingLeft:"1em" }} size='mini' focus placeholder='Max'  />
            </List.Content>
        </List.Item>        

       </List>
      </React.Fragment>

);

CategoryCheckBox.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  mylabel: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  checked: PropTypes.bool,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default CategoryCheckBox;
```

From the main program,
The component is called with the below parameters:

```
 <CategoryCheckBox name={item.value} mylabel={item.text} checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.value)} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Below is my screenshot for the component along with React debugger showing the checked value.

[image: screenshot for the component along with React debugger showing checked value]

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Tried to set up most of the important code - Newbie to React myself. Can't get the index.js in the working order. But it gives you a good idea of my code https://codesandbox.io/embed/2pyoxpr6rn?fontsize=14

Comment: its working fine for me, check this [working snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/wwkr492p1w), let me know if i misunderstood something

Comment: Yes, that works fine but when you have multiple children in the component using the react fragment.  It doesn't work. I have tried to set the disabled={true} and it works. It also throws another warning  - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Thanks for the speedy response though, Mayank.

Comment: can you create a sample working sandbox of your problem? that will be easy to check the actual issue.

Comment: Tried to set up most of the important code - Newbie to React myself. Cant get the index.js in the right shape. But it gives you a good idea of my code https://codesandbox.io/embed/2pyoxpr6rn?fontsize=14

Comment: Think the class-based component approach is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

1- You are not assigning the name to `CheckBox` element in `CategoryCheckBox`, add name here:

```
<Checkbox
  style={{ paddingLeft: "1em", paddingBottom: "1em" }}
  label={mylabel}

  // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ here
  name={name}
  checked={checked}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

2- Add disable condition for Max input field also:

```
<Input
  style={{ maxWidth: "9em", paddingLeft: "1em" }}
  size="mini"
  focus
  placeholder="Max"

  // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ here
  disabled={!checked}
/>
```

3- Most importantly, You are storing data in states in `App` component so it needs to be a class component.

Check [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqlpx52l5z) with all these changes.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code the problem is with your app component. Your app component has a state and therefore cannot be a stateless functional component. Your App component should look something like this.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Checkbox, Label, Header, Card, Form, Button, Container, Icon, Step, Select, Dropdown, List } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import womensBoutiqueOptions from "./womensBoutiqueOptions";
import CategoryCheckBox from "./CategoryCheckBox";
import "./styles.css";

class App() extends React.Component {
 


    state = {
        date: new Date(),
        time: '10:00',
        checkedItems: new Map()
    }
   
    handleChange(e) {
      const item = e.target.name;
      const isChecked = e.target.checked;
      this.setState(prevState => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked) }));
    }
  
    render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Form size="large" key="large">
                          <h4 className="ui dividing header">Womens Information</h4>

             <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                <Form.Field>
                     <React.Fragment>
                             <List horizontal >
                            {
                              womensBoutiqueOptions.map(item => (
                               
                                <List.Item key={item.key}>
                                    <List.Content>
                                       
                                       <CategoryCheckBox name={item.value} mylabel={item.text} checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.value)} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                 
                                  </List.Content> 
                                </List.Item>
                              ))
                            }
                          </List>
                    </React.Fragment>
                </Form.Field>
              </Form.Group>  
              </Form>        
            </div>
      )
    }
  );
}
```

Check out the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for some more information on why